# How can I input a command into CMD when using a BAT file?

Tags: batch-file, scripting, windows-scripting

I'm trying to create a `.bat` file which takes each `.txt` file in the directory and turns it into a `.csv` file by using `logparser`.

The common syntax for logparser is:

```
logparser "SELECT * INTO filename FROM filename" -I:txt -o:csv`
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
for /R %%x in (*.txt) do (echo logparser "SELECT * INTO filename FROM filename" -I:txt -o:csv
```

The problem I am encountering is that I'm `echo`ing the whole command but it is not executing.

I need this command executed:

```
logparser "SELECT * INTO filename FROM filename" -I:txt -o:csv
```

Comment: That's exactly the purpose of `echo`, which is to echo what follows it out to the console. What behavior do you expect besides exactly what it is designed (and documented) to do?

Comment: Why are you using a `FOR /R` command if you are not going to use the `FOR` meta-variable?

Comment: @KenWhite I need the command to get executed. 
Squashman I'm using it. It is not listed.

Comment: What do you think **`%%x`** is designated for?

Comment: @Compo I believe it is a variable. I have to use %%x instead of %x when using a for loop. BTW, thanks for editing my comment. My English is not the best either.

Comment: Yes but what for? If you're designating it, there must be a reason. `For` `metavariable` `in` `something` `do` `a command with the` `metavariable`. So your metavariable should be substituted into the do command!

Comment: Ah! I need it to run x times depending on the amount of files I find on the directory. So `for` `amount_of_files` `in` `path` `do` `command`. Forgive me but I'm used to doing things like `for (x = 0; x < 10; x++)` so I might be totally wrong on how I'm doing this.

Comment: If I take out the `echo` command, I get an error stating `logparser is not recognized...` If I create a `.bat` file and just put the `logparser` command on it, it works. This is what I'm trying to fix.

Comment: It essentially does 'for each .txt file assign it to %%x, _(the metavariable)_, then do a command on %%x, _(the .txt file)_. Each .txt filename will be individually assigned to %%x.

Comment: @Compo Thanks for clarifying that. All I need now is to figure out why the `logparser` command is not being used. Any ideas?

Comment: My guess is that your do command would be `logparser "SELECT * INTO filename.csv FROM filename.txt" -i:txt -o:csv`. Considering that `%%x` is assigned to `filename.txt`, and reading the help usage of `for` i.e. `for /?` shows you that `%%~nx` is assigned to `filename` only, your command should probably look like this: `logparser "SELECT * INTO %%~nx.csv FROM %%x" -i:txt -o:.csv`

Comment: Additionally, when reading the output from `for /?`, you'll note that `for /R %%x in (*.txt) do...` works recursively, i.e. assigns to each file in the directory and all subdirectories. You question doesn't mention subdirectories, so perhaps changing it do `for %%x in (*.txt) do...` is what you need instead. So putting it all together would look more like this:     `for %%x in (*.txt) do logparser "SELECT * INTO %%~nx.csv FROM %%x" -i:txt -o:.csv`.

Comment: If the batch file cannot find logparser then it is not located in the current working directory or it does not exist within a directory assigned to the system path variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my various comments put together as an answer.

If you're designating `%%x`, there must be a reason.
i.e. `For` `metavariable` `in` `something` `do` `a command with the metavariable`.
So your `metavariable` should be substituted into `do`'s `command`!

It essentially does, '`for` each `.txt` file assign it to `%%x`, *(the metavariable)*, then `do` `a command on %%x`, *(the .txt file)*'.
Each `filename.txt` will be individually assigned to `%%x`.

My guess is that `do`'s command would be:

```bat
logparser "SELECT * INTO filename.csv FROM filename.txt" -i:txt -o:csv
```

Considering that `%%x` is assigned to `filename.txt`, and reading the help usage of `for`, i.e. `for /?`, shows you that `%%~nx` is assigned to `filename` only; your command should probably look like this:

```bat
logparser "SELECT * INTO %%~nx.csv FROM %%x" -i:txt -o:.csv
```

Additionally, when reading the output from `for /?`, you'll note that `for /R %%x in (*.txt) do...` works recursively, i.e. assigns to each file in the directory and all subdirectories.

You question doesn't mention subdirectories, so perhaps changing it to `for %%x in (*.txt) do...` is what you need instead.

So putting it all together would look more like this:

```bat
for %%x in (*.txt) do logparser "SELECT * INTO %%~nx.csv FROM %%x" -i:txt -o:.csv
```

---

For `logparser` to work, it must be in the current working directory, *which in this case will be the same directory as your `.txt` files*, or in a directory specified in the `%PATH%` variable.

If neither of those are true, then you should provide the relative or fully specified path to it, for example:

```bat
for %%x in (*.txt) do "C:\Program Files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2\LogParser.exe" "SELECT * INTO %%~nx.csv FROM %%x" -i:txt -o:.csv
```

*Note:
filenames containing spaces or special characters would need special attention with regards quoting*.

Comment: Thank you very much! The reason the `logparser` command was not working is because I needed to have it in the same directory. The `for` loop does work nicely. I just need to figure out why it breaks when the file name has a non alphanumerical character.

Comment: @RandomName, see my footnote, _you'll need to consult the command line help for Log Parser to determine the appropriate syntax for the quoting of filenames._

Comment: Yes, saw it. Thank you again.